# Can't get this content spinning API to work with PHP

Tags: php, api, spinner

Can you help me get this [content spinning API](http://developer.spinnerchief.com/API_Document.aspx) working? It was wrote to work with C# but is there a way I can get it to work using PHP? I've been trying to post to the URL stated on that page using cURL, but all I'm getting back is a blank page. Here's the code I'm using:

```
$url = "http://api.spinnerchief.com/apikey=YourAPIKey&username=YourUsername&password=YourPassword";

// Some content to POST
$post_fields = "SpinnerChief is totally free. Not a 'lite' or 'trial' version, but a 100% full version and totally free. SpinnerChief may be free, but it is also one of the most powerful content creation software tools available. It's huge user-defined thesaurus means that its sysnonyms are words that YOU would normally use in real life, not some stuffy dictionary definition. And there's more...SpinnerChief can only get better, because we listen to our users, We take onboard your ideas and suggestions, and we update SpinnerChief so that it becomes the software YOU want!";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 9001);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $result;
```

Can anyone see something wrong I'm doing? Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Have you replaced 'YourAPIKey' et al with valid data?

Comment: Yeah :) It just sends back a blank page.

Comment: What do you get when you browse to the URL (bypassing the PHP script altogether)? Is the URL valid?

Comment: Same. A blank page. Could be because no text is getting 'POST'ed to it, which causes the blank page. I'm not sure. I've tried out the C# app and looked at the code. It uses this "wb.UploadString(mStr, "POST", textBox1.Text);" to send the text.

Comment: Perhaps I was unclear. What do you get when you browse to "http://api.spinnerchief.com/apikey=YourAPIKey&username=YourUsername&password=YourPassword" with the appropriate credentials in the place of `yourAPIKey`, `YourUsername` and `YourPassword`?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant. Nothing, just a blank page. Sorry if I was unclear :)

Comment: That is your problem, then. If the URL returns no data, your cURL statement will also return nothing. You will need to correct your credentials, or check with the 'spinnerchief.com' administrator for a correction.

Comment: Yeah, I'll contact them and ask. Just weird though because the C# app works and it only posts the text to that URL. Thanks for the help anyway George! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value for `CURLOPT_POST` should be `1`, and the posted data should be set with `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`.

Comment: Yeah, tried that as well. Still returns nothing. :( If it was posting correctly it should return an error or something at least, but it doesn't.

Comment: Ooh, yes. It returns "couldn't connect to host". But the site is live.

Comment: Are you `urlencode`-ing the URL parameters (key, username, password)? Special characters in the parameters might break the URL.

Comment: No I'm not, but they don't contain any special characters. I pasted them straight into the URL string. Could it be that the port 9001 is blocked causing it not to connect?

Comment: That's possible. You can check that using the browser, i.e. try accessing the site in the browser as `http://api.spinnerchief.com:9001/...`.